# Is there anyway to make GCC generate extra NOP instruction to align instruction execution to a certain block size?

Tags: assembly, gcc, cpu, cpu-architecture

Context: Hello, I have recently been building a custom CPU that has 16, 32, and 48bit instruction length. The CPU fetches 64bit blocks of data, and this is all fine until an instruction is caught in between two blocks of data; This makes my CPU fetch two blocks of data which affects its performance.

Question:
I wonder if there is any way to make gcc align instructions with NOPS to 64bit blocks by adding aditional parameters to the compilation process. Or what it the correct approach to make GCC align instructions with NOPS.

This is how an instruction gets caught in between two block.

```
          +---------------+ 
          |Unaligned ins  |
          +---------------+
 +---------------+ +---------------+
 |     64Bits    | |     64Bits    |
 +---------------+ +---------------+
```

The ideal way for 16bit execution and 48bit execution that I want GCC to achieve. Each empty block represent a 16bit instruction, but in the last big empty block represents a 48bit instruction; which will make unaligned the posterior instructions if another 48bit or 32bit instruction follows it, it will get caught in between two data blocks. I want GCC to generate a NOP instruction to prevent unaligned instruction execution. As shown in the last empty block.

```
+---+---+---+---+ +-----------+---+
|   |   |   |   | |           |   |
+---+---+---+---+ +-----------+---+
+---------------+ +---------------+
|     64Bits    | |     64Bits    |
+---------------+ +---------------+
```

What I have already tried:
I tried to add parameters to GCC such as `-falign-loops=## -falign-functions=## -falign-jumps= ##` But they dont achieve what im looking for.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but a similar thing is done in Google NaCl (native client) to make the analysis of x86 machine code easier.  Perhaps read up on the modifications they did to the toolchain to achieve this effect?

Comment: @fuz Oh, thanks. Can you please provide me with a link?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a link.  I would have to research the subject the same way you need to.

Comment: @fuz Oh, okay. No worries, I will try to find it my self. Thanks for the informacion tho.

Comment: I doubt there's anything in GCC already that can do this for you.  It's something you should be able to implement yourself by annotating RTL insns with their instruction size and then implementing your own custom pass. You could also implement it in the assembler.

Comment: @RossRidge What would be the assembler approach?

Comment: What you're doing is similar to the instruction bundles of the Itanium (IA-64) architecture so looking at that implementation may be helpful but otherwise it would be just like with GCC except the assembler already knows the instruction sizes.

Comment: It's your custom machine, so you're writing the assembler, no?  So write your assembler to check if each generated instruction would cross the boundary, and to insert padding before it if so.  Make this feature optional if you like - enabled by a command-line switch or a directive which you have gcc insert.

Comment: @NateEldredge It a custom CPU core, based around the Moxie ISA. I'm using the toolchain provided by the creator of the ISA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you have GCC print `.p2align 3,,4` before every 48-bit instruction, and `.p2align 3,,2` before every 32-bit instruction? I don't know exactly where to modify GCC's source code to do that, but it avoids needing to actually track instruction sizes and current alignment.

That will pad for alignment to a 2^3 byte (64-bit) boundary, but only if it requires at most 4 bytes (or 2 bytes) of padding.

With those limits, it *won't* pad before a 6-byte instruction if it's 6 bytes ahead of a chunk boundary (and thus can fit).  Same for a 4-byte instruction.

More optimal would be instruction-scheduling that's aware of boundaries and tries to re-order to pack into chunks without leaving large gaps to fill with NOPs.

---

If your GAS doesn't know how to generate 2 or 4 byte NOPs itself, the bad simple way would be to use `.p2alignw 3, 0x1234, 4` to tell it to fill with 2-byte sequences of `0x1234`.  (Where `0x1234` is a placeholder for the encoding of a 2-byte NOP instruction.)

Slightly less bad would be teaching GAS to emit 2-byte or 4-byte NOP instructions instead of 2x 2-byte NOPs, but this is just a dirty hack you can do without modifying GAS.

Comment: It works. I deleted my previous comment, I was wrong. Now the issue is that the padding is executed as an instruction, and `objdump -d` displays "bad", like if the padding was a bad instruction.

Comment: @Bybit360: So GAS for that ISA doesn't know how to pad with NOPs, only with `00` bytes or something?  You might need to teach it how to use a 2 or 4 byte NOP.  Or as an even worse hack for proof of concept, just use `.p2alignw 3, 0x1234, 4` where `0x1234` is the machine code for a 2-byte NOP.  That's worse than one 4-byte NOP if there are 4 bytes to fill, I assume.  I agreed with Ross in comments that GCC probably knows how to bundle instructions for some VLIW ISAs like IA-64 so you might be better off treating your ISA like that to get it to try to pack instructions better.

Comment: Well, with the `.p2alignw` approach compiling some simple test code without optimizations; about 1/3 instructions end up as NOPs, with optimizations no NOPs are generated. I think this might be the easiest hackiest and laziest approach. But it works lol.